# AWS: How to pass the resource defined in API gateway to lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I try to build a simple Rest API. I only know how to pass query strings to my lambda functions with mapping. Now I wonder whether there are ways to pass the "resource" to my lambda function?

For example, how can my lambda get "fruit" and "vegetable" please?

[image]

Comment: I added an answer, all we need is to check `Use Lambda Proxy integration` in your screen shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a mapping in the `mapping template` like below I defined for my resource named `fruits` which is a `GET` HTTP method.

[$context Variables for data models, authorizers, mapping templates, and CloudWatch access logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference)

[image]

It will be available to your lambda as shown below in the logs.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Integration Request `LAMBDA` will pass the request body alone to Lambda

[image]

Where as Integration Request `LAMBDA_PROXY` will attach headers, query params, etc and send enriched request similar to how it is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html#api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda-test) and request body will simply be as string within `body`. This already contains everything that we need, api-key used, api-id, headers, stages, parms, etc. if we don't like this, then we can customize the request body by setting a custom mapping template(like the other answer)

[image]

We can enable Lambda Proxy integration by clicking on Integration Request and checking on `Use Lambda Proxy integration`
[image]