# Invoke same Lambda function from different API endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless

I am new to the serverless architecture design. Basically I wanted to read/update data from/to the mongodb database. To achieve this, I have created API Gateway with two resources ( list, update ) and created two lambda methods ( listFunction, updateFunction ).

Is there any way I can write in single lambda method and perform list/update based on the api gateway resource name?

Comment: Yes, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html you get all the api information, e.g. the path inside the `context` and `event`.

Comment: if you are looking for examples here [AWS: How to pass the resource defined in API gateway to lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66359212/aws-how-to-pass-the-resource-defined-in-api-gateway-to-lambda/66359417#66359417). Both ways are described via `proxy integration` as well as `template mapping` to get the `resource name` in the lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use single function to serve all your operations.

In api Gateway [event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html) you get the resource path and http method type.

So you can have `if else` block to handle the request based on path in your handler.

In your api Gateway configure both the methods with new lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

To create a Lambda function that can perform CRUD operations on MongoDB, first make sure that you deploy a MongoDB instance to an EC2 instance as discussed here:

[Install and configure MongoDB community edition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/sbs/CHAP_MongoDB2DocumentDB.02.html)

Once you verify that the MongoDB instance is succesfully deploy and running, now you can write a Lambda function that perform CRUD operations. I would write the Lambda function using the **Lambda runtime Java API** and then use the **Mongo Java API** to interact with a MongoDB collection.

For example, create a **MongoClient** instance in your Lambda function.

```
    private String mongoUri = "mongodb://<ENTER EC2 IP Address>.amazonaws.com:27017" ;
       private MongoClient getConnection() {

       try {
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI(mongoUri));
        return mongoClient;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now you can perform CRUD operations from within a Lambda Function.

If you want to use API Gateway, you can invoke this Lambda function using API Gateway.