# Getting error response = null from api gateway and dynamoDb

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, aws-sdk, aws-amplify

{
"error": "Cannot read property 'playerId' of null"
}

I have created a list lambda function

that passes in a playerId. This playerId is used like so.

```
export const main = handler(async (event, context) => { 
const data = JSON.parse(event.body);
const params = {
  TableName: process.env.teamsTable,
  ExpressionAttributeValues : {
    ':playerId' : { S: data.playerId }
  },
  FilterExpression: "contains (players, :playerId)"
};
try {
  const result = await dynamoDb.scan(params);
  if (!result.Items) {
    throw new Error("Teams not found.");
  }

  return {
    status: 200,
    body: result.Items,
  };
} catch (e) {
return {
  statusCode: 500,
  body: JSON.stringify({ error: e.message }),
};}});
```

I have tested it locally with serverless mocks and it works. Create a call to use it in the FE and hitting this error: {error: "Cannot read property 'playerId' of null"}
error: "Cannot read property 'playerId' of null", also hit it through API gateway and hitting same.
frontEnd call -

```
  const endpoint = "/teams";
  console.log(playerId);
  try {
    const response = await API.get(amplifyAPIName, endpoint, {
      body: playerId
    });
    return response;
  } catch {
    return [];
  }
}
```

help

Comment: is api gateway defined with Lambda or Lambda_Proxy ? we can check/change this setting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66359212/aws-how-to-pass-the-resource-defined-in-api-gateway-to-lambda/66360396#66360396) , for your code, you need Lambda_Proxy.

Comment: Is it because of putting the body in the `GET` method?

Comment: Yes! Ahhh thank you!

Comment: That's fortunate.Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Answer: I was using the get method instead of post. I am passing playerId as a filter expression in aws. By changing it to post I was able to receive my results.