# Lambda behaves differently when invoked from Console (test) and through AWS Gateway REST API

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

***Problem:*** Pandas behaves differently when

1. I call it from the "invoke" test (and via AWS Gateway which is pointed to the said Lambda)
2. I call it through a REST API via AWS Gateway
   Lambda works fine with A) (it returns intended values) but does not work with B) (returns NaN values).

***Details:*** I have a simple python script in a Lambda (python 3.8). With the code, I have uploaded pandas, numpy and a .csv file into the Lambda. I built a rest API with AWS Gateway that uses the Lambda as a resource.

My objective is to load the .csv into a Pandas dataframe when Lambda is requested, then filter the dataframe with the event parameters to find particular values, and return those values.

Sample code below.
Any help would be appreciated.

***Code***

**Lambda:**

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    # extract filter values from request
    vendor =  event['Vendor']

    # load the csv
    data = pd.read_csv('vendor_data.csv')
    print("Data shape", data.shape)

    # correct types
    data.quantity = (data.quantity).apply(lambda x: int(x))
    data.loc[:,'Vendor'] = data['Vendor'].astype('str') # I also tried astype('string'), doesn't change

    # filter the dataframe with Vendor == vendor
    condition = (data.Vendor.str.contains(str(vendor))) #I also tried (data.Vendor == vendor)
    data  = data.loc[condition]

    #verify it worked: it works with 'invoke' but not through rest API
    print('First five rows', data[['Vendor']].head())

    data = data['quantity'].apply(lambda x: int(x))
    sum = data.sum()

    return sum
```

***Gateway Rest API***
*Request model template:*

```
{  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "title": "Request",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "Vendor": {
            "type": "string"
        },
    },
    "required": ["Vendor"]
}
```

*Response model template:*

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "title": "Response",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "sum": {
            "type": "number"
        }
    }
}
```

***Example test (post to rest API)***

```
PARAMS = {
    "Vendor": "2202630"
}
PARAMS = json.dumps(PARAMS)
print(PARAMS)
r = requests.post(url = URL, data = PARAMS) 
print(r.content)
```

results in:

```
{ "Vendor": "2202630"}
b'{"statusCode": 200, "body": NaN, "event": {"Vendor": "2202630"}, "data": "[]"}'
```

***Example test (through AWS Gateway):***

Request:
{
"Vendor": "2202630"
}

Response body:

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": 599,
  "event": {
    "Vendor": "22026305"
  },
  "data": "[50 44 38 45 50 45 38 26 18 31 21  9 53 47 45 39]"
}
```

Comment: Are you using [Lambda or Lamba_Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66360396/10186808) integration in Api Gateway?

Comment: No proxy integration ("Use Lambda Proxy integration" is unchecked).